# How do I fix the error "select list expression [...] references which is neither grouped nor aggregated" in BigQuery?

Tags: select, group-by, google-bigquery, reference, aggregate

I get the error "select list expression Opportunity.id references which is neither grouped nor aggregated" when running the following query in BigQuery:

```
SELECT
  Opportunity.id AS `Opportunity_Id`,
  Opportunity.testing_only__c AS `Opportunity_Testing_only`,
  MAX(DatedConversionRate.startdate) AS `DatedConversionRate_Start_date`,
FROM
  `dataset.Opportunity` Opportunity
LEFT JOIN 
  `dataset.DatedConversionRate` DatedConversionRate 
  ON DatedConversionRate.isocode = Opportunity.currencyisocode
WHERE
  DatedConversionRate.startdate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `Opportunity.id` from `select` or group by it:

```
SELECT
  Opportunity.id AS `Opportunity_Id`,
  MAX(DatedConversionRate.startdate) AS `DatedConversionRate_Start_date`,
FROM
  `dataset.Opportunity` Opportunity
LEFT JOIN 
  `dataset.DatedConversionRate` DatedConversionRate 
  ON DatedConversionRate.isocode = Opportunity.currencyisocode
WHERE
  DatedConversionRate.startdate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
GROUP BY Opportunity.id
```

Comment: If I add GROUP BY Opportunity.id, then the error is replaced with a similar error for the next selection: "select list expression Opportunity.testing_only__c references which is neither grouped nor aggregated"

Comment: group it too: `GROUP BY Opportunity.id, Opportunity.testing_only__c`

Comment: So if I have for example 30 fields that I select, I have to GROUP BY all of them?

Comment: If you have `max()` - then yes.